# No EFI System Partition was found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, 20.04

I am installing Ubuntu 20.04, already partitioned with the ext4 format, the mount point is "/". Then at the moment of giving it to install now. The following is displayed:

```
"No EFI System Partition was found. This system will likely not be able to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail. Please go back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk"
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are installing via the 'something else' option, have you selected the /boot/efi/ partition? as you don't mention it.

Comment: you're missing `/boot/efi` partition

Comment: I added the EFI partition to it, and it seems to be installing fine. This is rare from EFI, since the tutorials do not mention it.